# Laravel Exception: Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an error "Undefined variable: exams (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject01\resources\views\home.blade.php)" when I run my laravel code, which is shown below (the controller name is ExamController.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exam;

class ExamController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $exams = Exam::all();
        return view('home',compact('exams'));
    }
}
```

Here is the model named Exam.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Exam extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exams';
}
```

Here is my view, which is located in views/home named "home.blade.php":

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form method='POST' action='/posts'>

                       {{ csrf_field() }}


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Exams Name</label>
                            <select name="exam" id="exam" class="form-control input-sm depertment">
                                  <option value="" id="exam_slect">Select Exams</option>
                                 @foreach($exams as $exam)
                                  <option value="{{$exam->id}}">{{$exam->name}}</option>
                                 @endforeach                 
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Depertment</label>
                            <select name="depertment" id="depertment" class="form-control input-sm depertment">
                                  <option value="" id="dept_slect">Select Depertment</option>
                                 @foreach($depertments as $depertment)
                                  <option value="{{$depertment->id}}">{{$depertment->name}}</option>
                                 @endforeach                 
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Teacher</label>
                            <select name="teacher" id="teacher" class="form-control input-sm teacher">
                                <option value="#dept_slect">Select Teacher</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="start_date">Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Publish"></input>
                        </div>

                    </form>



                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection


@section('script')

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".depertment").change(function() {
            console.log($(".depertment").val());
            $.getJSON("/home/teacher/" + $(".depertment").val(), function(data) {
                var $teachers = $(".teacher");
                $teachers.empty();
                $.each(data, function(id, name) {
                    $teachers.append('<option value="' + id +'">' + name + '</option>');
                });
                $(".teacher").trigger("change"); /* trigger next drop down list not in the example */
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

I call the code from my browser with this http://localhost:8000/home***
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNxUg.png)

Here is is my error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
2/2
ErrorException in 6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php line 20:
Undefined variable: exams (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject01\resources\views\home.blade.php)
in 6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php line 20
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\storage\\framework\\views/6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'depertments' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\resources\\views/home.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'depertments' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\public\\index.php') in server.php line 21
1/2
ErrorException in 6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php line 20:
Undefined variable: exams
in 6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php line 20
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined variable: exams', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\storage\\framework\\views\\6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php', 20, array('__path' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\storage\\framework\\views/6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'depertments' => object(Collection)), 'obLevel' => 1, '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'depertments' => object(Collection))) in 6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php line 20
at include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\storage\\framework\\views\\6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\storage\\framework\\views/6da755f502f5377537b5d00f9f88cb42e31cc6de.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'depertments' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\resources\\views/home.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'depertments' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject01\\public\\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: plz dump the result of `$exams = Exam::all();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: You wrote "and here is my view, it is located in views/home named home.blade.php". So is the view is located in `/views/home/home.blade.php`?